# How to sync time from GPS using NTP On Gentoo

Tags: linux, gps, gentoo, gpsd, gps-time

I have a problem in synchronizing system time with GPS time.
I am using U-Blox GPS Receiver. The GPS receiver is working fine through /dev/ttyXR4 port.The problem now, I want the system to automatically update itself with GPS time using NTP client.

I have installed gpsd and also net-misc/ntp-client on my Gentoo machine.
I ran cgps, and xgps, the GPS receiver is totally working fine.

my ntp.conf looks like this : (I copied this from Ubuntu since I did this once and it works fine with Ubuntu)

```
 pool us.pool.ntp.org iburst

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
logfile /var/log/ntp.log

restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1 mask 255.255.255.0
restrict -6 ::1

# GPS Serial data reference
server 127.127.28.0
fudge 127.127.28.0 time1 0.9999 refid GPS

# GPS PPS reference
server 127.127.28.1 prefer
fudge 127.127.28.1 refid PPS

# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access,
# but only if cryptographically authenticated
#restrict 192.168.123.0  mask  255.255.255.0 notrust

restrict 192.168.1.0  mask  255.255.255.0 nomodify
```

so, anyone can guide me with this problem to feed the time from GPS to NTP and afterwards change my system setting automatically??

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: http://www.catb.org/gpsd/gpsd-time-service-howto.html

Comment: hi @Nodak , I have been following that guide since the day 1 I started doing this task but however, it's not working on my machine.

Comment: How is your GPS device connected? Serial (RS232) or USB? Which sentences are you receiving from the GPS receiver? What is the output of `ntpq -pcrv`?